# Does Apache Cassandra db have a async driver?

Tags: cassandra

I am looking for a Cassandra async jdbc driver.  I have seen one from Mongodb.  I have seen the async queries like documented here https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries but that is not what I mean.

Comment: you mean really JDBC driver, or just Java driver?

Comment: I am looking for the Cassandra async jdbc driver.

Comment: when you mean async, I supposed running queries without waiting for results. Having a non blocking IO right?

Comment: I mean a async jdbc driver.  Kind of like Mongo has one here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver-async/.